# How to change the color of an svg image?

Tags: svg, tailwind-css

I'm trying to change the color of this svg img, using TailwindCSS classes:

```
<svg class="fill-current text-white-500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M4 4h16a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6c0-1.1.9-2 2-2zm16 3.38V6H4v1.38l8 4 8-4zm0 2.24l-7.55 3.77a1 1 0 0 1-.9 0L4 9.62V18h16V9.62z"/></svg>
```

and I have the following:

```
<svg
    class="fill-current text-white inline-block h-20 w-20"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M4 4h16a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6c0-1.1.9-2 2-2zm16 3.38V6H4v1.38l8 4 8-4zm0 2.24l-7.55 3.77a1 1 0 0 1-.9 0L4 9.62V18h16V9.62z"/>
</svg>
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Depends on what your CSS contains and you haven't shown us that.

Comment: I haven't applied any css whatsoever

Comment: What do you think class="fill-current text-white inline-block h-20 w-20" should do then? What is fill-current? What is  text-white inline-block? etc.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using tailwind: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/fill/#app

Answer (score 0):

In Tailwind, there is no <strike>`text-white-500`</strike> it's just `text-white`.

So far you are doing it right by using fill-current. Simply added `fill-current text-red-600`. This will change the svg color to #E53E3E. Check the [color palette](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#default-color-palette)

Comment: I have this currently:

<svg class="fill-current text-white inline-block"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="50px" height="50px"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M4 4h16a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6c0-1.1.9-2 2-2zm16 3.38V6H4v1.38l8 4 8-4zm0 2.24l-7.55 3.77a1 1 0 0 1-.9 0L4 9.62V18h16V9.62z"/></svg>
Doesn't work

Comment: That means your svg is in **white**. What color you want?

Comment: it's not. I see it in black

Comment: Do you have any parent tag with **text-black**. If yes, then remove that and try. If no, then add the svg inside a div tag and add text-white to that div tag.

Comment: There aren't any black parent divs either

Comment: I also facing the same problem. always see black svg if the text-<color>-<below than 500>

Answer (score 0):

Now you can simply use `<svg class="fill-white" ...></svg>` or any  color dynamicaly with their hex code like `fill-[#fcfcfc]`